# Oracle 11g External Table (file) about skipping data

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, external

I am using the external table approach with Oracle 11g to load data from files to the database.

The files come from external sources and are of standard format.  However, my application does not need all the columns (fields in file) for each row.  Is there a way I can specify which columns should be sourced and which should  be ignored (by, for example, providing an offset).

Comment: Can you describe the format of your file?  Are we talking about a fixed width file, for example, or a delimited file?  Your use of the word "offset" sort of implies fixed width but I'm not sure that was intentional.

Comment: Hi.  Yes, the file is a fixed width file with end of line delimited and the External table definition has the the length of each field mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data file is fixed width, you can simply omit the portions of the line that you're not interested in.  There is no requirement that your field specifications are continuous.

For example, rather than specifying

```
(
  col1 (1:1) CHAR(1),
  col2 (2:2) CHAR(1),
  col3 (3:3) CHAR(1)
)
```

to load the first three characters in the line into a separate column, you could skip the second column and just load the first, third, and fourth positions in the file into three separate columns.

```
(
  col1 (1:1) CHAR(1),
  col2 (3:3) CHAR(1),
  col3 (4:4) CHAR(1)
)
```

Comment: Just one more request.  Do you have an online example of this?